# Why select options created by JS are limited or are not shown?

Tags: javascript

A very interesting thing hapens to my code.I have 3 different selects,one for years, the second for months  and the third for days.I created options for the years and days via JS. My problem is my years list starts from the start  point  but dosn't end  in the finish point I give,but when I'm changing the start point of j to 300  for instance, everything works perfectly.What is the reason or maybe    my code is not correct?   https://jsfiddle.net/arminemash/f9gy1p4L/15/

```
 select{float:left}
  #month,#days,input{display:none} 

 <body onload='addOptions()'>
    <form action=''>
      <select required id='year' class='selectOption' onchange='select(this)'>
         <option value=""> Select year</option> 

      </select>
       <select required id='month' class='selectOption' onchange='select(this)'>
        <option value=""> Select month</option>
        <option value="January">January</option>
        <option value="February">February</option>
        <option value="March">March</option>
        <option value="April">April</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="June">June</option>
        <option value="July">July</option>
        <option value="August">August</option>
        <option value="September">September</option>
        <option value="October">October</option>
        <option value="November">November</option>
        <option value="December">December</option>
      </select>

    <select required id='days' class='selectOption' onchange='select(this)'>
      <option value="">Select Day</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" class='selectOption' onclick='getDate()'> 

  </form>
</body>


function addOptions(){    
   var x= document.getElementById('year');  
   var y = document.getElementById('days'); 
   for(var i=1900,j=1;i<3000,j<=31;i++,j++){
     var option1 = document.createElement("option");
     var option2 = document.createElement("option");
     option1.text =i;
     x.add(option1);
     option2.text =j;
     y.add(option2);
   }
}

 var i=0;           
 function select(par){
    var x=document.getElementsByClassName('selectOption');
    if( par.selectedIndex !== "0"){ 
      x[i+1].style.display='block';             
      i++;
      collectData.push(par.value);
    }       
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean, you've stopped the loop at 30 iterations by adding multiple conditions ?

Comment: `j<=31` takes prevalence over the `i` iterator.

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do? Each iteration must satisfy both conditions `i<3000,j<=31`. Since after 30 iterations `j<=31` is no longer true, then the loop stops. If you don't care about `j`, just remove it from the loop and use just`i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your for loop. `for(var i=1900,j=1;i<3000,j<=31;i++,j++)` this will stop when j reaches 31. What you need is two for loops one for days and one for years. I edited your fiddle [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/8gy3d0y1/)

Comment: No problem, we've all been there